# How to convert csv file's specific column to string List

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

Does anyone know how to convert a specific column in a csv file to string List ?
I am trying to have a 'contact number' list from csv file.  (Please see my csv file in below)

## Intending to do

```
List<string> contactNumberList = new List<string>();
-- contactNumberList.Add("1888714"); (Manual)
---contactNumberList.Add("1888759");(Manual)
```

## In my CSV

```
"Email","Opt In Date","Opted Out","Opt In Details","Email Type","Opted Out Date","Opt Out Details","Contact Number","Salutation"
"test1@testApp.com","05/01/2014 11:23 AM","F","User Name: capn@goldpop.org.uk. IP Address: 62.213.118.139","0","","","1888714","Mrs Hall"
"test2@testApp.com","05/01/2014 11:23 AM","F","User Name: capntransfer@goldpop.org.uk. IP Address: 62.213.118.139","0","","","1888759","Mrs Heyworth"
```

Comment: Please don't parse the CSV file yourself. You're going to have a bad time. Instead, use a third-party library like https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper.

Answer (score 1):

For parsing CSVs I suggest using a ligrary a s simply splitting by line /columns separator can bring to errors if the values are escaped.

I.e.

> "Mr John, Bob Smith"

is a valid CSV as it is escaped with quotes. But a Split function will stop working.

One valid choice is LumenWorks (you can find it in NuGet).

I.e.

```
using (var csv = new CsvReader(r, false, csvParserConfiguration.ColumnSeparator, '"', '"', '#', ValueTrimmingOptions.None))
{            
 // Read lines
 while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
 {
  contactNumberList.Add[7];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the file line by line, `Split()` by commas, select the desired column, trim quotes off and add to a list?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int columnId = 3;
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\test.csv");
var list = lines.Select(line => 
       { var values = line.Split(';');
         return values[columnId];
       });
```

Comment: Why using the inline function instead of just directly using lines.Select(line => line.Split(';')[columId]) ?

Comment: I can't use like this IEnumerable<string> strings = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(silverpopDownloadedFile)
                .Select(x => x.Split(',')[7]);  because 'Contact Number' could be any position everytime csv file generated.  Now at 7. Next time could be at 5

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\test.csv"));
List<string> contactNumbersList = new List<string>();
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
   var line = reader.ReadLine();
   var values = line.Split(',');
   contactNumbersList.Add(values[7]);
}
```

but better yet you could use a dedicated library like [CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader).

Comment: Sorry. ContactNumber position could change.  Today at 7. Tomorrow it will be at 5.

Comment: By inspecting First Line of CSV (column header) you can find out column index of Contact Number, then use that index in further csv rows reading.

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<string> strings = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines({filepath})
                                  .Select(x => x.Split(';')[{columnId}])
```